# Reduce the space between two canvas html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to place two canvas nearby. But unfortunately when i include two canvas it automatically produces a space between two canvas. How to remove that empty space or how to join that two canvas. Here is my fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ7MR/)

here is my code:

```
<canvas id="button" width="30" height="30" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;background-color:green;"></canvas> 
<canvas id="button" width="30" height="30" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;background-color:green;"></canvas> 
​
```

here is the script:

```
window.onload=function()
{
var canvas = document.getElementById("button");
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
}​
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The newline in the HTML is being treated as a space. Simply get rid of the whitespace between the two canvases:

```
<canvas id="button" width="30" height="30" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;background-color:green;">
</canvas><canvas id="button" width="30" height="30" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;background-color:green;">
</canvas>
```

See [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/CQ7MR/2/)

Or use:

```
<canvas id="button" width="30" height="30" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;background-color:green;"></canvas><!--
--><canvas id="button" width="30" height="30" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;background-color:green;"></canvas>
```

Comment: sorry and thanks. I thought its a property of canvas. Its totally my mistake.